# What are the most widely useful RFCs in the context of API security and Oauth?

Tags: api, security, rest, rfc

What are the most widely useful RFCs in the context of API security and Oauth?

Any pointer to a list of such RFCs and basic summary information with some examples of usage would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At least there is "OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations" aka. rfc6819 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819).

Comment: Very useful. Thanks Disenchant.  Keep it coming folks :)